# Send HTML data to PHP and post back the result to HTML page with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am trying to send an input text value "Username" to a php script which is giving a result. That result I want it back on the html page.

```
    <input type="text" id="user" name="user" placeholder="Username">
    <button type="button" id="fetchBtn">Click Me!</button>
    <p id="txt"></p>
```

Javascript inside my website

```
<script>
let fetchBtn = document.getElementById('fetchBtn');
fetchBtn.addEventListener('click', buttonClickHandler);

function buttonClickHandler() {
    
    // Instantiate an xhr object
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    
    // What to do when response is ready  
    xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
        if(xhr.readyState === 4) {
            if(xhr.status === 200) {
                document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML = 
                xhr.responseText;
            } else {
                console.log('Error Code: ' + xhr.status);
                console.log('Error Message: ' + xhr.statusText);
            }
        }
    }
    xhr.open('GET', 'data.php');
    
    // Send the request
    xhr.send();
}
</script>
```

Now I am trying to get the PHP variable $title back to HTML page after it's processed by the php script. I can't figure out how to display it properly

```
<?php 
function file_get_contents_curl($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}

$para = $_GET['user'];
$html = file_get_contents_curl("http://website.com/$para");

//parsing begins here:
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);
$nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');

//get and display what you need:
$title = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
?>
```

Comment: Where is `$para` coming from in your PHP code? The line is commented out.

Comment: (Unrelated) fyi: `type="name"` doesn't exist, probably should be `type="text"`

Comment: Thats the thing, I don't know how to pass the inputed value to equal $para. If I get the input value to the php variable then I use the $para to get the website title. Then the website $title needs to be back on the html website @droopsnoot

Comment: Yes, @brombeer that is true. I modify that

Comment: Get rid of `<html><body>`...that should not be part of the AJAX response - you're not starting a whole new HTML document, you're just returning some data which should be embedded within an existing one.

Comment: @ADyson those were some of my tests to make sure the php is working. I need to use inputed text as php variable $para, then to get back the resulted $title variable into a span text for example

Comment: No such test would require those tags, though

Comment: Hello, I just solved everything with this line : xhr.open('GET', 'data.php?user=' + document.getElementById('user').value); . Passing the input field to php as parameter then getting the response back to my main website

Answer (score 0):

Your not sending any data back, the XHR is GET in which case you'll have to query vars on the end of the url `data.php?user='+user.value`, better to use POST

and in your PHP user `$user = $_GET['user'];`

But not 100% what your asking but your code examples...

Comment: It would need to be `+user.value`

Comment: Hello, I just solved everything with this line : xhr.open('GET', 'data.php?user=' + document.getElementById('user').value);   . Passing the input field to php as parameter then getting response in my main website